# WPF binding Not working

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am new to `WPF`. I have developed this test `MVVM` Application using `WPF`. But binding does not work. But as far as my knowledge no errors can be detected. can any one help on this. below images and coding shows the test app.

[image]

[image]

`Student.cs`

```
using System;<br/>
using System.Collections.Generic;<br/>
using System.Linq;<br/>
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfNotifier
{
    public class Student : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this._name; }
        set
        {

            this._name = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    private string _company;
    public string Company
    {
        get { return this._company; }
        set
        {
            this._company = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Company");
        }
    }
    private string _designation;
    public string Designation
    {
        get { return this._designation; }
        set
        {
            this._designation = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Designation");
        }
    }
    private Single _monthlypay;
    public Single MonthlyPay
    {
        get { return this._monthlypay; }
        set
        {
            this._monthlypay = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("MonthlyPay");
            this.OnPropertyChanged("AnnualPay");
        }
    }
    public Single AnnualPay
    {
        get { return 12 * this.MonthlyPay; }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: rather attaching images you could attach the xaml, cs code itself..

Comment: Thanks.. Dj ill do next time

Comment: Errors in your bindings will appear in the Output window when you're debugging.  If you have some, sharing them will help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

binding just work for **public properties**, so your

```
 <Grid DataContext="{Binding Path=st}">
```

did not work. you have to set this.DataContext = this; in your MainWindow ctor. btw why do you need a static student object?

```
  public MainWindow()
  {
     ...
     this.DataContext = this;
  }
```

with this code your datacontext is your mainwindow and now your binding can work.

to check DataContext and Bindings at runtime you can use [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: then you should update your question, because there st is just a static field

Comment: @Arkenstone: your screenshot clearly shows `public static Student st = new Student()` - this is a *field*, not a *property*.

Comment: @Arkenstone: Properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x9fsa0sw(v=vs.100).aspx  Fields: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms173118(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: `public Student st { get; set; }` i change the field into property . but still no result showed in binded text box

Comment: see my edit pls. you need the right datacontext so that your binding can work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach the `Student` instance `sc` to the window `DataContext`. 
In the `MainWindow` contructor add the line:

```
this.DataContext=sc;
```

Many mvvm library can sort of do this automtically. Without any of this you can define an embedded resource of type Student and set it to the DataContext of the window.
But as a suggestion, if you want to start with MWWM, try some already made OSS library.

Comment: That worked fine.. But is there way to do without using DataContext in codbehind... I mean use DataContext only in XAML

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind(xaml.cs) file after the `InitailizeComponent();` statement add the following piece of code:

```
this.DataContext=new Student();

Add the default constructor in Student.cs
public Student()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. for the response. Arushi i'm just trying to use Datacontext in XAML rather than code behind. is it possible